# How to include Database in mobile itself for offline android app?

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite, localhost

I am building an android app to work in the area of NO-Internet_Connectivity,And its not possible to hardCode all the data.

The app takes the input from users -> Search accordingly in DB -> and returns output.

I want some method so that I can keep my mobile itself as a database and fetch the data accordingly.

Comment: There are several libraries that offer database functionality, including SQL. A few minutes in Google should offer quite a few choices.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways some are InMemory(HashMap, ArrayList etc), RoomDB etc. You can choose as per your requirement.

Comment: Can you please brief!

Comment: First, understand this ..
https://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/
then this,
https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/
then you are ready to manipulate according to your requirements